# c++17 add class with deleted copy constructor to std::vector at compile time

Tags: c++, vector, c++17, copy-constructor, move-semantics

Below is a class that I've defined with a deleted copy constructor and copy assignment operator. This is the only assumption that has to be made.

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
    explicit MyClass(int i) : i(i) {}

    MyClass(const MyClass&) = delete;
    MyClass& operator=(const MyClass&) = delete;

    MyClass(MyClass&& other) :
        i(std::move(other.i))
        {}  

    MyClass& operator=(MyClass&& other) {
        i = std::move(other.i);
        return *this;
    }   

    private:
    int i;
};
```

The goal is then to add my class to a std::vector at compile time.

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<MyClass> v{MyClass{0}, MyClass{1}, MyClass{2}};

    return 0;
}
```

My compiler is telling me that the STL requires the use of my deleted copy constructor `MyClass::MyClass(const MyClass&)` but is there any way around this?

I am already aware of a possible way to add values at runtime but the below is a poor solution in my opinion because I've lost the compile time check.

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<MyClass> v;
    v.emplace_back(MyClass{0});
    v.emplace_back(MyClass{1});
    v.emplace_back(MyClass{2});

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see no way to avoid copying objects when placing them into a vector, whether during construction or after. This can't be done. A vector requires, at a minimum, a copyable boject.

Comment: What do you mean by compile time check? Please, give an example

Comment: Another possibility is to allocate the objects on the heap and store their pointers (or use smart pointers)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My compiler is telling me that the STL requires the use of my deleted copy constructor `MyClass::MyClass(const MyClass&)` but is there any way around this?

No, you can't.

`initializer_list` creates a hidden array for you, which is declared `const`, roughly evaluated like this:

```
// pseudo code
const MyClass __arr[3] = { MyClass(1), MyClass(2), MyClass(3) };
std::vector<MyClass> v{ std::initializer_list<MyClass>{ __arr, __arr + 2 } };
```

If you want to avoid copying, you'll have to stick to `emplace_back` like you said.

> I am already aware of a possible way to add values at runtime ...

By the way, your example is **not** the proper way to use `emplace_back`:

```
std::vector<MyClass> v;
v.emplace_back(MyClass{0});
v.emplace_back(MyClass{1});
v.emplace_back(MyClass{2});
```

You're still creating `MyClass` and then move it to `v`, which is quite a common mistake when using `emplace`-ish functions.

What you really wanted to do is probably as follows:

```
v.reserve(3);
v.emplace_back(0);
v.emplace_back(1);
v.emplace_back(2);
```

This way you're avoiding *accidentally* invoking move constructor, and just constructing the object at the right place **only once with no move, and no copy**.

> The goal is then to add my class to a `std::vector` at compile time.

If you want to create an array at compile time, use `std::array` instead.
`std::array` is exactly designed for that purpose:

```
std::array<MyClass, 3> v = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Comment: looks like my solution is going to involve the array! Thank you

Comment: @Max `std::array` is the right idea, unfortunately the `explicit` constructor will make this a bit trickier than advertised. I don't have a good solution for that or I'd have written an answer half an hour ago.

Comment: And I'm stupid. It's what you were trying with the `vector`: `std::array<MyClass, 3> v = {MyClass(0), MyClass(1), MyClass(2)};`